# Cannot update icecast metadata with libshout

Tags: java, icecast

I have created my own source to stream to icecast (2.4.2) using libshout  (with [java bindings](https://github.com/OlegKunitsyn/libshout-java)). I can stream music all perfectly fine but I cannot update the metadata of a mount (which I could do when I was streaming using my own implementation in Java).

When I update using the libshout functionality

```
libshout.setMeta("song", "song-title-here");
```

I get an exception that says "No error" (irony appreciated, but message not really helpful).

I managed to update the metadata with http request - but **works only if the request comes from [the same IP as the source](https://github.com/xiph/Icecast-Server/blob/72075d0d0dd97c54d2317b325bfec55a7d496f82/src/admin.c#L1053)**. For reference, the request looks like this.

```
curl --user admin:hackme -X "GET" "http://localhost:8000/admin/metadata?mode=updinfo&song=xyz&charset=UTF-8&mount=%2Ftest"
```

Would be nice (but happy I'm no longer stuck) to be able to send the request via libshout

Comment: What's the container and codec for that stream?

Comment: I am streaming MP3 files (mpeg v1 L3). In libshout I set the format for MP3 (shout_set_format 1)

Comment: libshout is not really that helpful with its messages. You should also look at the icecast error.log. if necessary, increase log level to 4.